# Program won't display string if it contains one string from list

Tags: python, filter, any

I want to filter some strings I get. For example I have this string :

```
str = "I just go on Facebook today"
```

With a list of banned words like this :

```
banned_words = ["facebook", "Facebook", "Netflix"]
```

How could I do something like: "If none of the banned words are in the string", so I can process the string?

With some search I find the function `any` and try something like :

```
if any(word not in str for word in banned_words):
```

But doesn't work at all `:/`

Comment: Do you care about the `uppercase`? and can you also put your expect result data ?

Comment: I think I could test it on a lowercase(str) to reduce the banned_words list yes. And the expected result is pretty simple : I don't want to process `str` if it contains one or more `banned_words`. I don't think I could be more clear..

Comment: you'd better put your expect result as example, cause your describe isn't clear .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the following

```
if not any(word  for word in banned_words if word in str):print(1)
```

Note: Never use keywords as variable names. here `str` is a keyword. so, i suggest you to use some other variable name

Comment: @Frank it takes an iterable. Such as a generator

Comment: Not sure this is correct. `if word in str` checks substrings, not proper "tokens" of the string. Plus, you're filtering the banned words list based on if it exists, so the `not ` needs removed, I think.

Comment: For my application, that's perfect. Thanks a lot :) Don't worry for the var name, that was just for the example

Answer (score 3):

You can use `in` with a for loop

so it work like this

```
s = "I just go on Facebook today"

banned_words = ["facebook", "Facebook", "Netflix"]

exist = False
for word in banned_words:

    if (word in s):

        print('banned words "{}" found in str'.format(word))
        exist = True

        break

if (not exist):

    print ('Banned words not found in str')
```

output:

```
banned words "Facebook" found in str
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `banned_words` has many items, You can transform it from `list` to `set`. And check if all the words in the sentence are not in the `banned_words`:

```
banned_words = set(["facebook", "Facebook", "netflix"])

if all(word not in banned_words for word in sentence.split()):
    pass
```

Comment: Maybe lowercase the sentence?

Comment: It's depend on the content of `banned_words`. If it contains all form of one banned word, we needn't transform the word to lowercase.

Comment: My point is that the question seems to want `Facebook` to be considered as banned, where this answer doesn't provide that

Comment: The original `banned_word` of question contains `Facebook`. I omit it for simple. I just transform the data structure of it not modify the content of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know which word isn't include in your string, try below way:

```
your_str = "I just go on Facebook today"
banned_words = ["facebook", "Facebook", "Netflix"]
[word for word in banned_words if word not in your_str]
```

And you should got a result like below:

> ['facebook', 'Netflix']

And if you want to know which word you have the same in your string:

```
[word for word in banned_words if word in your_str]
```

> ['Facebook']

You want to use `any` to test if it's exist, that's no a good way! should check what it is inside the result! `any` is just a checker for `bool`, as it's name imply `any([True, False, False])` will return `False`, but here you can see all we have is a `string` type. so do no matter how you try, always return `True`.

```
>>> any(['a', 'b','c'])
True
```